# What could be a dataset in which the presence of an outlier dramatically affects the performance of Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) regression?

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling, regression, linear-regression

I am tasked with giving an example of a dataset in which the presence of an outlier dramatically affects the performance of
Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) regression. I've searched and searched the web and I understand that OLS has a hard time dealing with outliers, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why, and finding a dataset to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a real-world data set here is one on [Harvard's Dataverse that examines state social politics research](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/16431) for outliers for the same purpose you are looking for. If you are looking for one for more illustrative purposes one data set worth knowing is [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) for demonstrating how misleading some descriptive statistics can be. For your own investigations, many data sets with and without outliers can be found on [Google's beta dataset search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch) and are worth exploring if you are curious!

Comment: I will definitely look into those. Especially the quartet is interesting to me.  Thanks for the help, It is much appreciated!